# How to deploy apps with Microsoft Graph support

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

basically I want to deploy a NET.Core application where Calendar data will be read from an Exchange server account.
So the user has to fill out his login data and that it.

This works fine with Exchange.Webservices in Windows, but Exchange.Webservices are not working in Linux due the .NETFramework dependency.
I also tried the "Sherlock Exchange.WebservicesStandard" package which is also not working.

Microsoft Graph is a product I don't understand.
Is is correct, that every user needs to have an Azure Account and his own APPID?
If that is correct, this product seems to be a little bit useless in my opinion.

Any ideas?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer, you will need an appid for your application which you will get from https://portal.azure.com/.  Users of your application will not need any of this. 
Please see this link with Quick Starts to help you with development using Microsoft Graph https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start

Comment: Thank you Betti! This makes more sense. best regards!